# How can I test with jest a httpClient that is using axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a service that in some moments I need to call an external API. For making this calls more easy written, I created a httpService. For now I only have a post method that will receive a url and data.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const httpClient = axios.create({
  headers: {
    common: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
})

export async function post(url, data) {
  try {
    const response = await httpClient.post(url, data)
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error('Error in POST request')
  }
}
```

I need to write some tests for this code using jest, but as my url is generic, i want to pass a url like "http://test.com/api" and fake a positive result. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) package:

> Axios adapter that allows to easily mock requests

E.g.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

describe('76630221', () => {
    test('should pass', async () => {
        const { post } = await import('./');
        mock.onPost('http://test.com/api').reply(200, {
            code: 0,
            message: null,
        });
        const data = await post('http://test.com/api', { name: 'nick' });
        expect(data).toEqual({ code: 0, message: null });
    });
});
```